# UIViewcontroller disappear after switch tabs UITabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uisearchcontroller

I'm working on an app that uses `UITabBarController` and sudenlly one tabItem stops to appear. Then I start to investigate and end up with a problem related with `UISearchController` and `UITabBarController`.

[image]

To isolate the problem a build a simple app to demostrate the situation.

This is how I instanciate the TabBar at `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` :

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    self.window?.backgroundColor = .white

    let first:SearchController = {
        let sc = SearchController()
        sc.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "First", image: UIImage(named:"iphone"), tag: 0)
        return sc
    }()

    let second:SecondViewController = {
        let s = SecondViewController()
        s.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Second", image: UIImage(named:"iphone"), tag: 1)
        return s
    }()

    let tabBar = UITabBarController()
    let controllers = [first, second]
    tabBar.viewControllers = controllers.map {
        UINavigationController(rootViewController: $0)
    }


    self.window?.rootViewController = tabBar
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
```

This is the viewController with UISearchController:

```
class SearchController: UIViewController {
    var matchingItems:[String] = [] {
        didSet{
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    lazy var searchController:UISearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

    lazy var tableView: UITableView = { [unowned self] in
        let tv = UITableView(frame: CGRect.zero, style: .grouped)
        tv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tv.delegate = self
        tv.dataSource = self
        tv.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "id")
        return tv
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        title = "First"
        view.addSubview(self.tableView)
        self.navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        self.perform(#selector(showKeyboard), with: nil, afterDelay: 0.1)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        searchController.searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
        let layout = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layout.topAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layout.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layout.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layout.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    @objc func showKeyboard() {
        self.searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
        self.searchController.searchBar.text = ""
    }
}
```

In run time, when system finished rendering this view controller, the debug console print this:

```
SearchBar+TabBar[15454:895018] [MC] Reading from private effective user settings.
2018-04-22 12:07:19.595887-0300 SearchBar+TabBar[15454:895018] +[CATransaction synchronize] called within transaction
2018-04-22 12:07:19.608090-0300 SearchBar+TabBar[15454:895018] +[CATransaction synchronize] called within transaction
2018-04-22 12:07:19.608269-0300 SearchBar+TabBar[15454:895018] +[CATransaction synchronize] called within transaction
2018-04-22 12:07:19.608516-0300 SearchBar+TabBar[15454:895018] +[CATransaction synchronize] called within transaction
```

Searching on the stackoverflow I found that this message `+[CATransaction synchronize] called within transaction`
 is related to rendering more than one animation in the main thread.

I'm wondering if this viewcontroller visualisation problem is related to that. So I commented the `searchController` instantiation line in SearchController class:

```
self.navigationItem.searchController = searchController
```

Now the `UITabBarController` works perfectly without the `UISearchController` in my first view controller.

My questions are:

1. **Is there another way to instanciate UISearchController to avoid
   this?**
2. **If yes, how should I do that?**

GitHub repository with the sample code: [sample code](https://github.com/gazolla/SEachBar-TabBar)

Comment: I think this situation will never rise. How can you switch the tab item after keyboard did appear? Keyboard is cover the entire tabbar. (in actual scenario, in physical device/simulator with simulator keyboard)

Answer (score 1):

In Your TabBarController class implement this function:

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool
```

In this function you should check if Controller with searchBar was selected before and make SearchController inactive

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    if (tabBarController.selectedIndex == ControllerWithSearchBarIndex) {
        ((viewControllers![ControllerWithSearchBarIndex] as! UINavigationController).viewControllers.first! as! ControllerWithSearchBarIndex).searchController.isActive = false
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A friend of my suggests to add `UITabBarController` as root of `UINavigationController` in the at `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and it works perfectly and solve the problem:

```
let tabBar = UITabBarController()
let controllers = [first, second]
tabBar.viewControllers = controllers.map {
    UINavigationController(rootViewController: $0)
}


let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: tabBar)
nav.isNavigationBarHidden = true
nav.navigationBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `definesPresentationContext = true` on the view controller with the tableView (`SearchController` in your example). This will allow the `UISearchController` to remain active when you switch tabs.